# Troubleshooting in JDBC/Postgres Authentication Example

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to teach myself Java Servlets and JSP, and I am having an issue with authenticating with Tomcat 7 and Postgres 9.1.

It seems to be error free (Tomcat is not throwing any JAVA errors in its log file) and working however it is missing something because it never lets me authenticate. Almost like the username and password does not match whats in my table spaces within postgres.

Is there a way to introduce extra logging into my code so that I can see what is being queried and what is being returned and why there is a mismatch. This will certainly help my troubleshooting efforts.

For your information I am attaching my context.xml (META_INF), web.xml (WEB_INF) and my login html)

I appreciate your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

    <!-- Define two security roles -->
    <security-role>
        <description>customer service testers</description>
        <role-name>testing</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>system developers</description>
        <role-name>developer</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <!-- Restrict access to all files in the /admin folder -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- Authorize the programmer and service roles -->
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>developer</role-name>
            <role-name>testing</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Use form-based authentication -->
    <!--<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/admin/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/admin/login_error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    --> 

    <!-- Use basic authentication -->

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Admin Login</realm-name>
    </login-config>


     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/AUTHExample">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"
          driverName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
          connectionName="postgres" connectionPassword="postgres"
          userTable="userpass" userNameCol="user" userCredCol="passwd"
          userRoleTable="userrole" roleNameCol="rolename" 
          />

</Context>




<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning to Authenticate</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Admin Login Form</h1>
<p>Please enter your username and password to continue.</p>
<table cellspacing="5" border="0">
  <form action="j_security_check" method="get">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you testing Basic authentication with a login form?

Comment: you will see that form authentication is commented out, I was flicking between the two. It did not seem to make any functional difference

Comment: Yes, of course I noticed. But you included the HTML page with the form in it. Which is only relevant when testing Form Based Authentication. How are you testing your Basic Authentication?

Comment: This will probably demonstrate my ignorance as to the difference between the two but.... I was just flicking between the two by commenting out the login conflict I was not using. My preference is to use form authentication, however neither seems to be working hence my question going to troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, with form based authentication you create a login and login error page, and configure them in your web.xml. Whenever a user tries to access a protected resource they get forwarded to the login page. With basic authentication, the browser mediates the login process (with dialog boxes) and you do not need any custom page. It's also possible to include the Basic Authentication headers manually, and avoid dialog boxes altogether.

Comment: Ok,  Any hints for troubleshooting? Is there a way to print out the results of the database query so I can match the HTML Get with the contents of the database tables so I can hone in where the issues are? Visually, they look identical but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved my problem and considering how often this seems to come up I thought I would answer it for future people who stumble across it.

The problem I was having above was due to different column names for username in the user/password table and the rolename table. SQL had assigned it "user" instead of user.

Of note, if the role isnt defined properly in the web.xml, a 403 error displays when the username and password is correct.

Hope that was a help

Thank you